# Row formatting in ag-Grid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ag-grid

We need to conditionally make a row text as Bold. Currently its working on only single cell but we need to apply text bold on all columns cells. After applying the formatting 'isBold' column must be hide/remove. This column is used only for formatting. How to apply text-indent: 10px; of first column where the isBold column contains true value? Any possibility to achieve this?`here is plunker`
    http://plnkr.co/edit/YVGpi2FkwzCl3R1K8fwo?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of old, but for future references you can now just use `getRowStyle(params)`. I believe in your case you would use it like:

```
gridOptions.getRowStyle = function (params) {
    return params.data.isBold ? {"font-weight":"bold"} : null;
}
```

This assumes the `isBold` column you mention has its values as booleans (`true` & `false`). Else you just need to change the condition.

To hide the column you just **don't put its colDef with the others**, and that will simply not render it but you will still have access to the data contained in it (like here above).

Answer (score 1):

This plunker is not valid any more.

I believe that you use `cellStyle` callback of the `columnDefs` to make the font bold.

If you need to do it for the whole row, create a common callback function and use it in `cellStyle` of all `columnDefs`.

There is no single command to change the style of a row.