# Modify an ag-grid row after rendering

Tags: ag-grid

I need to slightly modify a ag-grid row after it has been rendered. In ag-grid, the actual HTML elements are not necessarily persistent, so manually-set styles may fall off.

For one thing, I have to modify the selection checkbox to set its `tabindex` to `-1`. This can technically be done in the `cellRenderer` callback, although it looks quite hacky. (The checkbox can be found at `params.eGridCell.children[0].children[0].wrappedElement`.)

But I also have to add a CSS class to some rows to highlight them based on external criteria. I haven't found a way to do this at all.

The best solution would seem to be using some sort of after-rendering callback, but to my knowledge no such thing exists.

I found a couple of related questions, but they were both resolved via `cellStyle`, which would not suffice here:

- [Row formatting in ag-Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613584/row-formatting-in-ag-grid)
- [How to provide a background color for an entire row in ag grid based on a certain value in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200358/how-to-provide-a-background-color-for-an-entire-row-in-ag-grid-based-on-a-certai)

Comment: Did you look here ? https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-cell-styling/index.php you can use cellClassRules to adapt your class style to your needs. Use the eGridCell parameter has nothing off hacky, it was added in purpose you need it so i don't see any problem of doing it.

Comment: `cellClassRules`, understandably, puts classes on cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not 1 but 3 options:

`getRowClass(params)`:

> Callback version of property 'rowClass'. Function should return a string or an array of strings.

`getRowStyle(params)`:

> Callback version of property 'rowStyle'. Function should return an object of CSS values.

`processRowPostCreate(params)`:

> Allows you to process rows after they are created. So do final adding of custom attributes etc.

In this last one you have the row in `params.eRow`.

All taken from https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-callbacks/index.php

Comment: `processRowPostCreate` is what I really need -- however, this is new functionality that was introduced just yesterday! In lieu of that, `getRowClass` will do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, Niall has been bussy this last week. But hey, `getRowClass` get's A LOT done with just a few css classes and a few conditionals. Glad to help :)